# Dynamically allocate array in struct - c

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, allocation

Trying to dynamically allocate data from a csv file. I am trying to make an array of structs holding 2d arrays. The problem is that I get a access violation when attempting to allocate memory for the array inside the struct. Marked problem area with comment. Any help is appreciated.

```
 typedef struct current{

    char **data;

}*CurrentData;

CurrentData getData(FILE *current){

CurrentData *AllCurrentData = malloc(NUM_ITEMS * sizeof(CurrentData));

    /*allocate struct data memory, skipping the first line of data*/
    while ((ch = fgetc(current)) != EOF){
        if (firstNewLine == 0){
            firstNewLine++;
        }
        if (firstNewLine > 0){
            if (ch == '\n'){
                AllCurrentData[newLineCount]->data = malloc(COLUMNS * sizeof(char));  //problem here//
                newLineCount++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is newLineCount initialized to 0?

Comment: @OldProgrammer There's no main, so I think he just displayed the "important" code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This following line:

```
CurrentData *AllCurrentData = malloc(NUM_ITEMS * sizeof(CurrentData));
```

shall be:

```
CurrentData AllCurrentData = malloc(NUM_ITEMS * sizeof(*CurrentData));
```

Also replace this:

```
AllCurrentData[newLineCount]->data
```

with this:

```
AllCurrentData[newLineCount].data
```

Reason: your have `typedef`ed `CurrentData` to be an pointer to `struct current`, and you could directly allocate `AllCurrentData` as an array of `struct current`.